# Read GLB file with Draco and MeshCompression extensions

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit, gltf

I want to read .glb file it has compressed file from .gltf, GLTF file was reading from GLTFScenekit and GLTFKit2 libraries. But after compressed to glb it wasn't reading and getting crashed.showing error like this

```
Failed to load glTF asset: Error Domain=com.metalbyexample.gltfkit2 Code=1012 "Asset contains unsupported required extensions: (
    "KHR_mesh_quantization",
    "EXT_meshopt_compression"
)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Asset contains unsupported required extensions: (
    "KHR_mesh_quantization",
    "EXT_meshopt_compression"
)}
```